# Annotate param in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

I am struggling to find a way to annotate param in fat arrow function. Here, let me show it to you in example:

```
angular.forEach(someIterable, (item, key) => {
   // here I need item to be annotated
})
```

So I tried:

```
/**
 * @param {MyType} item
 */
angular.forEach(someIterable, (item, key) => {
   // here I need item to be annotated
})
```

And even:

```
angular.forEach(someIterable, (/** @type {MyType} */ item, key) => {
   // here I need item to be annotated
})
```

But nope, its not working. Of course I can do something like his inside the arrow function, but I don't want to.

```
/** @type {MyType} */
let annotatedItem = item;
```

Is there any way of doing this? I can extract the arrow function into separate variable and then just pass it as second argument to forEach, but I don't want to do that either, because it would make my code much less readable.

Comment: "But nope, its not working." ? What? How not?

Comment: IDE can't understand it (Intelijj IDEA)

Comment: I see... Recent versions (e.g. 2016.2) should do that for ECMA6 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/javascript-specific-guidelines.html#d1031464e34

Comment: not working in IDEA 2017.1.3

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.forEach(someIterable,
/**
 * @param {MyType} item
 */
(item, key) => {
   // here I need item to be annotated
})
```

yes that's an ugly place for the comment to be